# TSQL Use ' in string assignment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, quote

Trying to use a single quote and assign it to a variable so I can create a dynamic report.

The problem is when I do this:

```
set @Statequery = (' and PostalState = ' ')  +  @PostalState  + '''
```

If you do this, `print @Statequery`, it needs it to look like this.

```
and postalState = 'QLD'
```

How do I escape the ' character in this case?

Thanks for your help in advanced,

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it by doubling it:

```
set @Statequery = (' and PostalState = ''') + @PostalState + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @PostalState  VARCHAR(50)='QLD'
DECLARE @Statequery VARCHAR(max)
set @Statequery = ' and PostalState = ''' +  @PostalState  +''''   
PRINT @Statequery
```